# Increase margins for rotated axis labels with Crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I need to increase the space for axis tick labels that have been rotated.  The code below illustrates, and here's a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/mvhtqu17/).  Is this possible with crossfilter or do we have to get into the d3?

[image: See how x-axis tick labels are cut off..]

HTML

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/square/crossfilter/master/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dc-js/dc.js/develop/dc.js"></script>

<span>
  <div id="petchart"></div>
</span>
```

JS

```
j = [{'pet': 'Felis catus'}, {'pet': 'Canis lupus familiaris'}, {'pet': 'none'}, 
        {'pet': 'Felis catus'}, {'pet': 'Melopsittacus undulatus'}, 
    {'pet': 'Canis lupus familiaris'}, {'pet': 'Canis lupus familiaris'}];

cf = crossfilter(j);
pets_chart = dc.barChart("#petchart");
petDimension = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d.pet;});
petCountGroup = petDimension.group();

pets_chart
  .dimension(petDimension)
  .group(petCountGroup)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Felis catus","Canis lupus familiaris","Melopsittacus undulatus","none"])) 
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .width(300).height(250)
  .colors(['#1f77b4']).colorAccessor(function(d, i){ return i; })
  .xAxis().ticks(2);

dc.renderAll();
```

CSS

```
g .x.axis text {
    text-anchor: end !important;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's also possible to set bigger bottom margin with dc.js:

```
pets_chart
   .margins({ top: 10, left: 30, right: 10, bottom: 100 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/fts3tevj/

Comment: @geotheory this solution should be more robust

Comment: You're right this is better for the reason you described.  Thanks again dude

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with CSS:

```
.dc-chart svg {
  overflow: visible
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/70jx74c5/

Comment: You're welcome. My solution will probably cause another problems when placed in a bigger context. I mean the overflowing part may affect other elements on a webpage. It was just a first thought about how to solve this.