# Simple Barchart group by string name with DC.js D3.js & crossfilter.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to create a bar chart from some simple data in json format, where a funding amount is given various states of the United States. I would like to also find the total funding for each state where states are repeated.
I know the graph won't look great because dc.css is commented out.

I see now that the problem is that I can't group by a string i.e. "NY". But is it possible some other way?

Here is the all code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.5/dc.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/dc.css" media="screen" /> -->
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Bar Chart</h2></div>
  <div id="barchart"></div>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      state: "NJ",
      fund: 2811.59
    }, {
      state: "NC",
      fund: 449.98
    }, {
      state: "NY",
      fund: 174.53
    }, {
      state: "NC",
      fund: 500.32
    }, {
      state: "MD",
      fund: 420.87
    }, {
      state: "OR",
      fund: 2300.71
    }, {
      state: "PA",
      fund: 360.59
    }, {
      state: "NY",
      fund: 508.91
    }, {
      state: "PA",
      fund: 454.91
    }, {
      state: "PA",
      fund: 357.85
    }];

var fundingBarChart = dc.barChart("#barchart");
var ndx = crossfilter(data),
stateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.state;
}),
state_funds = stateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.fund;
});
fundingBarChart
  .width(500).height(200)
  .dimension(stateDim)
  // .renderArea(true)
  .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length + 1]))
  .dimension(stateDim)
  .group(state_funds)
  .brushOn(true)
  .legend(dc.legend().x(50).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
  .yAxisLabel("Funding by State")
  .xAxisLabel("State")
  .elasticX(true);

// dc.renderAll();
fundingBarChart.render();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe this is completely the wrong way to do this.

**EDIT**

I got to work by changing the data a little to,

```
var data = [{
run: 1,
state: "NJ",
fund: 2811.59
}, {
run: 2,
state: "NC",
fund: 449.98
}, {
run: 3,
state: "NY",
fund: 174.53
}, {
run: 2,
state: "NC",
fund: 500.32
}, {
run: 4,
state: "MD",
fund: 420.87
}, {
run: 5,
state: "OR",
fund: 2300.71
}, {
run: 6,
state: "PA",
fund: 360.59
}, {
run: 3,
state: "NY",
fund: 508.91
}, {
run: 6,
state: "PA",
fund: 454.91
}, {
run: 6,
state: "PA",
fund: 357.85
}];
```

and adding

```
stateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
// return d.state;
return d.run;
}),
```

and it does render the graph. But I don't know why I can't group on the state names.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using a post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593825/increase-margins-for-rotated-axis-labels-with-crossfilter) I solved it.

Here is the code index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.5/dc.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/dc.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Bar Chart</h2></div>
  <div id="barchart"></div>
  <script>
    var text = '[';
    var obj;
    url = "/funding";
    d3.json(url, function(error, json_response) {
      for (var item in json_response['proposals']) {
        item = parseInt(item);
        fund = json_response['proposals'][item]['totalPrice'];
        state = json_response['proposals'][item]['state'];
        obj = '{ "state":' + '"' + state + '"' + ', "fund":' + fund + '}';
        text += obj + ',';
      }
      text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
      text += ']';
      data = JSON.parse(text);
      cf = crossfilter(data);
      fundingBarChart = dc.barChart("#barchart");
      stateDim = cf.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.state;
      });
      fundDim = stateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
        return d.fund;
      });
      fundingBarChart
        .dimension(stateDim)
        .group(fundDim)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["AK", "AL", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND",
          "OH",
          "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"
        ]))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .width(1200).height(400)
        .brushOn(true)
        .yAxisLabel("Funding by State")
        .xAxisLabel("State")
        .elasticX(true)
        .xAxis().ticks(2);
      dc.renderAll();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The flask file also needed is, services.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
import json
import urllib2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/funding')
def fundingByState():
    donors_choose_url = "http://api.donorschoose.org/common/json_feed.html?historical=true&APIKey=DONORSCHOOSE"
    response = urllib2.urlopen(donors_choose_url)
    json_response = json.load(response)
    return json.dumps(json_response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The dc.css file

```
.dc-chart {
    float: left;
}

.dc-chart rect.bar {
    stroke: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dc-chart rect.bar:hover {
    fill-opacity: .5;
}

.dc-chart rect.stack1 {
    stroke: none;
    fill: red;
}

.dc-chart rect.stack2 {
    stroke: none;
    fill: green;
}

.dc-chart rect.deselected {
    stroke: none;
    fill: #ccc;
}

.dc-chart .sub .bar {
    stroke: none;
    fill: #ccc;
}

.dc-chart .pie-slice {
    fill: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dc-chart .pie-slice :hover {
    fill-opacity: .8;
}

.dc-chart .selected path {
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: #ccc;
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.dc-chart .deselected path {
    strok: none;
    fill-opacity: .5;
    fill: #ccc;
}

.dc-chart .axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dc-chart .axis text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.dc-chart .grid-line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    opacity: .5;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dc-chart .grid-line line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    opacity: .5;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dc-chart .brush rect.background {
    z-index: -999;
}

.dc-chart .brush rect.extent {
    fill: steelblue;
    fill-opacity: .125;
}

.dc-chart .brush .resize path {
    fill: #eee;
    stroke: #666;
}

.dc-chart path.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.dc-chart circle.dot {
    stroke: none;
}

.dc-chart g.dc-tooltip path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-opacity: .8;
}

.dc-chart path.area {
    fill-opacity: .3;
    stroke: none;
}

.dc-chart .node {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dc-chart .node :hover {
    fill-opacity: .8;
}

.dc-chart .selected circle {
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: #ccc;
    fill-opacity: 1;
}

.dc-chart .deselected circle {
    strok: none;
    fill-opacity: .5;
    fill: #ccc;
}

.dc-chart .bubble {
    stroke: none;
    fill-opacity: 0.6;
}

.dc-data-count {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.dc-data-count .filter-count {
    color: #3182bd;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dc-data-count .total-count {
    color: #3182bd;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dc-data-table {
}

.dc-chart g.state {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dc-chart g.state :hover {
    fill-opacity: .8;
}

.dc-chart g.state path {
    stroke: white;
}

.dc-chart g.selected path {
}

.dc-chart g.deselected path {
    fill: grey;
}

.dc-chart g.selected text {
}

.dc-chart g.deselected text {
    display: none;
}

.dc-chart g.county path {
    stroke: white;
    fill: none;
}

.dc-chart g.debug rect {
    fill: blue;
    fill-opacity: .2;
}

.dc-chart g.row rect {
    fill-opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dc-chart g.row rect:hover {
    fill-opacity: 0.6;
}

.dc-chart g.row text {
    fill: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dc-chart g text {
    /* Makes it so the user can't accidentally click and select text that is meant as a label only */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10 */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.table-cell-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.dc-chart svg {
  overflow: visible
}

fundingBarChart
   .margins({ top: 10, left: 430, right: 10, bottom: 100 }
```

)